# How to make a subst a USB drive appear as a local (non-removable) drive?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, subst

I have a set of USB drives (e.g. WD My Book) with different test data sets in different directories. I need to mount these directories as a drive letter.

To accurately test the behavior, this drive letter must act as a local, or non-removable, drive. A simple subst propagates the type of drive, in this case USB removable drive.

How do i get this drive to pretend that is is local?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try a virtual machine.  You should be able to configure it with any combination of fixed and removable drives.

Comment: Which one will allow me to specify which drives are removable?

Comment: @Richard: I know that VMWare Workstation allows mounting a fixed drive from any file (you'd encode your data set into a "virtual disk" file) and also passthrough of a USB disk.  In the first case, the guest OS will see a SCSI or ATA fixed disk, in the second case a USB removable drive.  But other VM solutions should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

there is nice litte app doing that for you

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html

> USBDLM can for newly attached USB drives check if the letter is used
>   by a network share of the currently logged on user and assign the next
>   letter that is really available reserve letters, so they are not used
>   for local drives assign a letter from a **list of new default letters**,
>   also dependent on many different criteria as the active user, drive
>   type, connection (USB, FireWire), USB port, volume label, size and
>   others extract the letter from the volume label assign letters for a
>   specific USB drive by putting an INI file on the drive remove the
>   drive letters of card readers until a card is inserted show a balloon
>   tip with the assigned drive letter(s) define autorun events depending
>   on many different criteria activate a basic protection against
>   'BadUSB' devices; USBDLM can ask on arrival of a USB keyboard device
>   if it shall be activated